# Is there any way to display <Text> with a timer setTimeout() multiple times?

Tags: react-native, settimeout

I'm trying to return 9 differents Text with a 5 seconds delay between each ones but it's only working for the first Text

i've tried using

```
  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed: true})}, 2000);
    if(this.state.timePassed == false){
      return (
        <Text></Text>
      )
    }else if (this.state.timePassed == true{
      return(
        <Text>HELLO</Text>
      )
    }else if (this.state.timePassed1 == false{
............
  }
}
```

but not working
I have also tried

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed1: true})}, 4000);
    if(this.state.timePassed1 == true){
      return(
      <Text>test</Text>)
    }
}
```

but not working

Here is my screen

```
export default class Internet2 extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timePassed: false,
      timePassed1: false
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed1: true})}, 4000);
    if(this.state.timePassed1 == true){
      return(
      <Text>test</Text>)
    }
}

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed: true})}, 2000);
    if(this.state.timePassed == false){
      return (
        <Text></Text>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <Text>HELLO</Text>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is keep the texts in an array and a variable for counting how many times has it passed.

```
state = {
    texts = ['sometext', ...]
    textCount = 0
}
```

Then you will create a `setInterval` to loop in the time you want

```
componentDidMount() {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {textCount: prevState.textCount + 1}
        })
        if (this.state.textCount > this.state.texts.length) clearInterval(timer);
    }, theTimeYouWant);
}
```

And render the texts using `.map`

```
  render() {
      return (
        <View>
            {this.state.texts.map((text, i) => i <= this.state.textCount ?
               <Text>{text}</Text> : null
            )}
        </View>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, its in render and you have to go like:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timePassed: false,
      timePassed1: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed: true})}, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed1: true})}, 3000);
      return (
        <View>
        {this.state.timePassed == true ? (<Text>INTERNET</Text>) : null}
        {this.state.timePassed1 == true ? (<Text>TEST</Text>) : null}
        </View>
      )

  }
}
```

Comment: Adding a `setTimeout` in the render method isn't good, every render, you will be calling a new `setTimeOut`.