# How do you temporarily display different <Text> multiple times?

Tags: react-native, text, setinterval

I am trying to have a page that displays randomly generated numbers for five seconds each before disappearing. I am working based off of answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258389/is-there-any-way-to-display-text-with-a-timer-settimeout-multiple-times).

This is my current code right now, but I am getting a syntax error in "state." Can someone help me find the syntax error or have a better idea on how to temporarily display ?

```
const Test2 = () => {
    const var1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+2;
    const var2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+2;
    const var3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+2;
    const var4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+2;
 

    state = {
        texts = [var1, var2, var3, var4],
        textCount = 0
    }

    componentDidMount(); {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {textCount: prevState.textCount + 1}
            })
            if (this.state.textCount > this.state.texts.length) clearInterval(timer);
        }, 5000);
    }

    render(); {
        return (
          <View>
              {this.state.texts.map((text, i) => i <= this.state.textCount ?
                 <Text>{text}</Text> : null
              )}
          </View>
        )
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default Test2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a functional component, the Q&A you're referencing uses class based components. The way you call your state is different.

For your example, you should use the `useState` React Hook ([Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)).